# how to write this where clause in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have to filter an index that could accept in some cases comma separated values. Im working with Ecto, without phoenix (with cowboy).

my index will support some search like this

```
/users?ids=1,2,3&email=simple@email.com&another=something
```

where email field doesn't allow more than one parameter and ids supports more than 1 id

This is what I've tried

```
def list_all(query_params) do
    filtered_params = prepare_list_query(query_params)

    User
    |> where(^filtered_params)
    |> Repo.all()
  end

  # In order to simplify queries I decided to manage all queries as IN clause
  # it will returns [id: [1,2,3], email:["something@mymail.com"]]

  defp prepare_list_query(query_params) do
    query_params
    |> Map.take(~w(ids email another))
    # Careful: read reference #1 above
    |> Enum.map(fn {name, value} ->
      case name do
        "ids" -> {:id, String.split(value, ",")}
        single_param -> {String.to_atom(single_param), [value]}
      end
    end)
  end
```

It's tricky but my idea is to return

```
[id: [1,2,3], email:["something@mymail.com"]]
```

and then working all filters as IN clause.

This filter has to support to send zero, one or all parameters.

I'm brand new in elixir world and I’m doing my first steps.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Why no `?` in that search string: `/users&ids=1,2,3&email=simple@email.com&another=something`  →  `/users?ids=1,2,3&email=simple@email.com&another=something`

Comment: It was a mistake writing this post but yes firs & is ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enum.reduce/3` to dynamically build an ecto query based on the params

```
def list_all(query_params) do
    query = User # initial query

    query_params
    |> Map.take(~w(ids email another))
    |> Enum.reduce(query, fn 
      {_key, value} when value in [nil, ""], q ->
          q # ignore empty values          
      {"ids", value}, q -> 
          ids = String.split(values, ",")
          q |> where([r], r.id in ^ids) 
      {key, value} ->
          args = [{key, value}] 
          q |> where(^args)
      end
    end)
    |> Repo.all()
  end
```

In the reduce function you can add new clauses to handle different keys and values.